# sh :15: Syntax error: "(" unexpected

Tags: ibm

In DB2, I have created a schema named `win`, and the tablespace named `tb1`. When I try to create a table under these, I'm getting:

> Syntax error sh: 15: "(" unexpected

My code is:

```sql
db2 create table win.student(id_num int, name varchar(50), mail_id varchar(50), rank int) in tb1
```

Comment: You should be entering that command into an [IBM db2 database client](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=installing-db2-database-servers), not a shell

Answer (score 2):

You need quotes to protect the parentheses from interpretation by the shell.